# CPLEX OPL Syntax

Tags: cplex, opl

How to write those encircled constraints

[image]

in CPLEX OPL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use max.
See small example from https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zoomax.mod

```
int nbKids=300;

{int} buses={30,40,50};


dvar int+ nbBus[buses];
dvar int maxNbOfBusesGivenSize;

    
minimize maxNbOfBusesGivenSize;
     
subject to
{
 // logical constraint
 // maxNbOfBusesGivenSize is the max of all nbBus
 maxNbOfBusesGivenSize==max(i in buses) nbBus[i];
 sum(i in buses) i*nbBus[i]>=nbKids;
}

execute DISPLAY_After_SOLVE
{
  writeln("The max number of buses is ",maxNbOfBusesGivenSize);
  writeln("nbBus = ",nbBus);
}

/*

gives

The max number of buses is 3
nbBus =  [3 3 3]

*/
```